# How to apply twist deformer but keep shape of spheres

Tags: 3d, cinema4d

So I have the following image:[image]

I created three spheres, placed them in a `cloner` and applied the `twist deformer`. I then repeated this for the opposite side. Essentially the helix structure in the middle is made of two chains. The repeating unit in my `cloner` is the three spheres to the left of the helix.

The problem is when I apply the `twist deformer` it distorts my spheres to the point they are not spheres any more. How I can apply the `twist deformer` on my `cloner` but keep the shape of my spheres.

Comment: If you work in Blender, [we have a SE for that](http://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve your desired effect is to use a `matrix` object.

The `matrix` acts like a `cloner` but instead of containing cloned geometry, it only contains the positions, scales, and rotations (matrices) of the clones.

You can apply your `twist` to the `matrix` object, and then use the `matrix` to drive a `cloner` in *object* mode. The `cloner` will place the clones at the positions in the `matrix` object without deforming the geometry.

Here is a screenshot of one such setup:
[image: Matrix Cloner Setup]

Note that I have placed 4 spheres in one clone and 2 in the other, just to simplify the example slightly.